# Popup menu for multiple function inside the manipulate

Tags: functions, manipulate, popup

```
f[x_, a_] := Sin[a x];g[y_, b_] := Sinh[b y];k[z_, c_] := Cos[c z];Manipulate[p1 = Plot[f[x, a], {a, 0, 1}],p2 = Plot[g[y, b], {b, 0, 0.5}],p3 = Plot[k[z, c], {c, 0, 1.5}], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

I am trying to plot three functions inside the manipulate command. And want to put one popup menu like p1,p2,p3, So that which option user choose that plot should display.
But I don't have any idea how to do that, Please help me...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You say **And want to display the plot of all by using a popup menu.**  I am confused. If you want to plot all 3 functions at same time, then why do you want popup menu to select the function to plot?

Answer (score 3):

> And want to put one popup menu

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{ops, x},
  ops = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
    PlotStyle -> Red};
  Which[plot == "Sin", Plot[Sin[x], {x, -range, range}, Evaluate@ops],
   plot == "Sinh", Plot[Sinh[x], {x, -range, range}, Evaluate@ops],
   plot == "Cos", Plot[Cos[x], {x, -range, range}, Evaluate@ops]
   ]
  ]
 ,
 Grid[{{PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[plot, {plot = #} &], {"Sin" -> "Sin", "Sinh" -> "Sinh", 
      "Cos" -> "Cos"}]}}],
 {{range, Pi, "range"}, Pi/10, 2 Pi, Pi/10},
 {{plot, "Sin"}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {plot, range}     
 ]
```

You can add any additional controls as an  exercise :)

Comment: @Thanks Nasser... It's helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to control the parameters a,b,c, and I'm not sure exactly what sort of display you want for the controls in Manipulate, but here is an example where you can select the function and the scaling factor with Manipulate.

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin, Sinh, Cos}}, {{k, 1}, 0, 2, .1}]
```

Comment: Please format (all of ) your code properly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Not exactly sure what happened. Fixed.

Comment: Actually, I have three different functions. And want to display the plot of all by using a popup menu.

Comment: I have edited the code but still not sure how to include a popup menu here...

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[f[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin, Sinh, Cos}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {{k, 1}, 0, 2, .1}]`